# Given sets $A$ and $B$, show $\{A\} \times B$ is disjoint from $A$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assume $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary sets, not necessarily disjoint. Let us construct the new set $\{A\} \times B$, where "$\times$" is the Cartesian product. Why is this newly constructed set disjoint from $A$?

**Background:** I have been reading [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/858992/1027282) on a wrong proof of the Schroeder-Bernstein theorem, and how it can be fixed. At one point, it is stated that $\{A\} \times B$ is disjoint from $A$, independent of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I can somewhat understand putting a set-theory tag, since you might not read the tag description. But why do you put a general-topology tag here? The question has nothing to do with it.

Comment: If $\{A\}\times B\cap A\neq \emptyset$, then $(A, b)\in A$ for some $b\in B$. If we use Kuratowski's definition of an ordered pair $(x, y) = \{\{x\}, \{x, y\}\}$ this means $A\in \{A\}\in (A, b)\in A$. This would contradict axiom of foundation, since it implies that there cannot be a sequence $f(n)$ of elements with $f(n+1)\in f(n)$ for each $n$.

Comment: By the way, you don't need the axiom of foundation to get a set which is disjoint from $A$ and in bijection with $B$; see e.g. this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299285/proof-of-exchange-principle-in-set-theory/1240240#1240240

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are not disjoint, then $(A,b)\in A$ for some $b\in B$. Let $S=\{A,\{A\},(A,b)\}$. Since $A\in\{A\}$ and $\{A\}\in(A,b)=\{\{A\},\{A,b\}\}$ and $(A,b)\in A$, the nonempty set $S$ has nonempty intersection with each of its elements, contradicting the axiom of foundation.

Comment: You are using Kuratowski's definition of an ordered pair, right? That is when $S \cap (A, b)$ contains $\{A\}$ (which results from $\{A\} \in (A, b)$).

Comment: Yes, Kuratowski ordered pair.